# Car Jerks Early Morning

Tags: troubleshooting, volvo-440

I have a 1994 Volvo 440 2.0i Manual.

I noticed lately that when I start the car in the morning sometimes the engine runs normally but the moment I engage the gear to move, the car begins to jerk. When in Neutral it would not rev up at all no matter how I try to rev it.

The Cold start was checked and changed, the fuel pump was checked, the nozzle, manifold, spark plugs were checked and cleaned.

The car works slightly better in the morning but it still jerks every time I slow down. Could it be an air pipe leakage somewhere, timing slip, or brain box problem?

Any help in diagnosing the problem is welcome.

Comment: Possible throttle position sensor problem?

Comment: Once the vehicle is warmed up does it operate normally?